# How to populate a UITableView from a remote .plist file

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, plist

Sorry if this has been asked many times before, but nothing seemed to help my issue.

I have set up my app to work perfectly reading from local .plist files from within the app itself for testing purposes, but for the app to be of any use, I need to be able to update it on a web server and load it remotely.

Here is my current code for local plists.
How would I amend this with minimum changes elsewhere in the app?

Many thanks in advance.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Create a dictionary with the contents of Squad.plist
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Squad" ofType:@"plist"]];

    //Fill the Squad array with contents of dictionary under the key "Players"
    [self setSquad:(NSArray*) [dictionary objectForKey:@"Players"]];

    //Reload the table data
    [[self tableView] reloadData];

    [[self navigationItem] setPrompt:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to first download your remote .plist while showing a loading or something, and after it's downloaded, use it locally the same way you are doing now. There's no way to read it remotely.

Comment: Thanks, got it sorted now anyway :) really was easy!!